# Move file to (error) different directory in case of duplicate file name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which renames text files based on content of the first row of text.

The name of the saved text file could be <s>doubled</s> a duplicate.

I want to save <s>double</s> duplicate text files in a different directory "C:\Research syntheses - Meta analysis\Txt files ECS\out\double\".

```
Sub RenameTextFile()

    Const SpecialCharacters As String = "\,/,:,*,?,<,>,|,""," ' Modify this as neccesary
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, TextLine
    Dim char As Variant

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fol = fso.GetFolder("C:\Research syntheses - Meta analysis\Txt files ECS\out\")

     For Each fil In fol.Files

        FileName = fil

        Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

        Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True

            Do
                Dim tmpLine As String
                TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
                tmpLine = RemoveWhiteSpace(TextLine)
                If Len(tmpLine) = 0 Then
                    TextLine = tmpLine
                End If
            Loop Until Len(TextLine) > 0
            MyFile.Close

            For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
                TextLine = Replace(TextLine, char, "")
            Next

            fil.Name = TextLine & ".txt"
            Exit Do

        Loop

        MyFile.Close
    Next fil
End Sub
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re trying to accomplish. To handle errors you can use an On error statement. Please edit your questions and explain with examples what’s going on with your code and the expected results

Comment: i edited the comment, hopes this make it a bit more clearer.

Comment: What do you mean with doubled?

Comment: file name,(based on first line of text to come across) which can be double.

Comment: Please post an example. Something like if X is found in the first line of the file, I expect that the file is saved in the Y directory.

Comment: all files should be saved in the out directory, except if the file description is the same as earlier in the loop than it should be saved in out\error\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub RenameTextFile()
    Const SpecialCharacters As String = "\,/,:,*,?,<,>,|,""," ' Modify this as neccesary
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Const foldPath As String = "C:\Research syntheses - Meta analysis\Txt files ECS\out\"
    Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, TextLine, fol As Object, fil As Object
    Dim char As Variant, arrSavedFiles(), k As Long, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fol = fso.GetFolder(foldPath)
    ReDim arrSavedFiles(k)

     For Each fil In fol.Files
        FileName = fil
        Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
        Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
            Do
                Dim tmpLine As String
                TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
                tmpLine = Trim(TextLine)
                If Len(tmpLine) <> 0 Then
                    TextLine = tmpLine:  Exit Do
                End If
            Loop Until Len(TextLine) > 0
            MyFile.Close

            For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
                TextLine = Replace(TextLine, char, "")
            Next
            For Each El In arrSavedFiles
                If El = TextLine & ".txt" Then boolFound = True: Exit For
            Next
            If Not boolFound Then
                fil.Name = TextLine & ".txt"
                arrSavedFiles(k) = TextLine & ".txt"
                k = k + 1: ReDim Preserve arrSavedFiles(k)
            Else
                boolFound = False
                If Not fso.FolderExists(foldPath & "error\") Then MkDir foldPath & "error\"
                FileCopy foldPath & fil.Name, foldPath & "error\" & fil.Name
                Kill foldPath & fil.Name
            End If
            Exit Do
        Loop
        MyFile.Close
    Next fil
End Sub
```

This will do what (I understood) you need. But, **if there will be more then two files containing the same first line text**, you must adapt the code in a similar way. I mean, before copying the file in the 'error' folder you must fill another array and check the file existence there. And do something (create another folder, warn using a message etc.)...
The moved files name will not be changed! It can be if necessary, in the same piece of code, or run the code again for the 'error' folder.